# What is the right way to make custom main page?

Tags: theme-development

I am making a custom theme and I want the main page to be a gallery, not a blog,
is it right to change `index.php` to a gallery page (content wise) or should I use another page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are definately a few ways of achieving this functionality. I assume by "main page" you mean the home page...

a. Create a new page called "home" 
b. In your site settings change your homepage to point to the "page" home, rather then grabbing your 10 newest posts. 
c. Now you have a page hook which you can build a custom template for in one of two ways.

1.) Use wordpress "custom page templates" to create a new template and apply to the new "home" page in "edit page"
http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates

OR...

2.) You can simply create a new file called "page-home.php" (ensuring the slug of your new home page is "home") and WP will use this page template instead....

Solution 2 is more streamlined for progamming if your clients don't need to apply templates themselves.

Hope that's helpful to you

Comment: thanx, I was looking for a solution that will work out of the box after the theme installation so (2) seems like the right one

Answer (score 2):

`front-page.php` may be a more appropriate template. `index.php` is the fallback for all types so should probably remain generic. see the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#The_Template_Hierarchy_In_Detail) for details.